# Configuring KeystoneJS App with LetsEncrypt & Heroku

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, keystonejs

I'm using the `letsencrypt` option of KeystoneJS to automatically configure and maintain HTTPS information for my project. I'd like to be able to configure this to work with a custom domain on Heroku; I've followed [a previous guide](https://medium.com/keystone-js/lets-encrypt-keystonejs-81fd55db9a3d#.85wyj7e3z) to actually configure the HTTPS (which appears to work), but when I load HTTPS on my site, it says that my certificate is only applicable for `*.herokuapps.com`, and not for my actual domain. Do I need to configure the [Heroku SSL Beta](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-beta) addon in order for HTTPS to explicitly work with my domain? If I do, how can I provide it with the keys and certificates that it asks for, even though my HTTPS information is being generated on the server and not locally? (Rather, how might I be able to generate that information locally, then have both Keystone and Heroku use identical information)?

EDIT: As I understand it, I can [manually pass a certificate and key](http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#options-ssl) to the SSL options in Keystone, but I have no way of automatically maintaining those certificates unless I instantiate them with the `letsencrypt` Keystone option (as far as I know). I'm still confused how I can manually create the keys/certificates the first time, then use `letsencrypt` to maintain and update them (and *then* communicate the new information with Heroku when they need to be updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to upload the certificate to Heroku after creating it with Let's Encrypt. It isn't automatic and needs to be manually re-uploaded every three months, but it's better than nothing.

I wrote a guide about how to solve this issue, which you can read [here](https://medium.com/@shb95/lets-encrypt-on-windows-10-67205af707c). I used Windows 10 for the process, but it should be fine on Mac OS X/Linux as well.